# Сортировка массивов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Входящие данные : двухмерный массив

```
[
 [2,3,4,5],
 [3,2,4,5],
 [2,3,8,5],
 [6,1,23,5],
 [2,1,23,5],
 [6,8,2,2]
]
```

Нужно найти массивы с одинаковыми первыми элементами (в данном случае c (2))

```
[2,3,4,5]
[2,1,23,5]
[2,3,8,5]

[6,1,23,5]
[6,8,2,2]
```

И записать их в отдельный массив.
Проблема:как найти совпадения, что бы поиск по совпадения не давал дубликаты.В данном случае у первого массива нахожу совпадение с 3 и 6 , потом у 3 нахожу с 1 и 6, и так делее , если допустим внутренних массивов больше , или других(не с (2) как в примере) совпадений больше

Comment: Приведите ваш код.

Comment: Решение в лоб: в начале в цикле бежите и берете у массивов первый элемент, записываете в массив...... далее считаете каких элементов в массиве > 1 (то есть имеются совпадения по первым элементам)...... далее делаете еще один цикл по массивам, 
 сравнивая с первым массивом (где оказались элементы с количеством > 1) помещая каждый из массивов к соответствующему ключу О_о

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, зачем два прохода-то?

Comment: @Grundy в смысле вместо первого цикла использовать `array_column`? да можно...... или ты еще о чем-то?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в js нет богомерзких *array_column* :-D

Comment: @Grundy ой... я на метки не посмотрел)

Comment: это использование ассоциативного массива , я правильно понял ?

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK да. ассоциативный массив...... почти.... ключ будет - первый элемент массива, в котором будет содержаться массивы с наличием этой цифры в своем первом элементе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для группировки массива удобно использовать метод [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Для того, чтобы не бежать по массиву дважды, можно сохранять текущий индекс группы с максимальным количеством элементов и саму эту группу.

Код может выглядеть так:

```js
var src = [
  [2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 2, 4, 5],
  [2, 3, 8, 5],
  [6, 1, 23, 5],
  [2, 1, 23, 5]
];

var dest = src.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let key = cur[0];
  if (!acc.map[key]) {
    acc.map[key] = [];
  }
  acc.map[key].push(cur);
  if (isNaN(acc.maxKey) ||
    acc.maxKey != key &&
    acc.map[acc.maxKey].length < acc.map[key].length) {
    acc.maxKey = key;
    acc.result = acc.map[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  map: {},
  maxKey: NaN,
  result: null
});

console.log(dest.result);
```

---

Для обновленного вопроса, нужно добавлять в результирующий массив те элементы, которые уже повторяются. Код может выглядеть так:

```js
var src = [
  [2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 2, 4, 5],
  [2, 3, 8, 5],
  [6, 1, 23, 5],
  [2, 1, 23, 5],
  [6, 8, 2, 2]
]

var dest = src.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let key = cur[0];
  if (!acc.map[key]) {
    acc.map[key] = [];
  }
  if (acc.mapCount[key]) { // если ключ уже повторялся
    acc.result.push(cur); // добавляем сразу в результат
    return acc;
  }
  acc.map[key].push(cur);
  if (acc.map[key].length == 2) { // если ключ повторяется
    acc.mapCount[key] = true; // выставляем флаг
    acc.result.push(...acc.map[key]); // переносим в результат
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  map: {},
  mapCount: {},
  result: []
});

console.log(dest.result);
```

Comment: что-то непонятно... ты группируешь только если цифра 2 в начале? а если будут еще массивы, например  с 3 или 6 в начале - то плевать?)

Comment: не, я сворачиваю массив в объект, где ключ - это первый элемент подмассива, а значение - массив содержащий массива в которых первый элемент равен ключу.

Comment: В общем, кмк, это неправильно... ведь при исходном массиве `var src = [
  [2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 2, 4, 5],
[3, 211, 4111, 511],
  [2, 3, 8, 5],
  [6, 1, 23, 5],
  [2, 1, 23, 5],
[6, 1, 66, 666],
];`  получим `[2, 3, 4, 5],
  [2, 3, 8, 5],
  [2, 1, 23, 5]` ..... а должно быть разбито по дублирующимся ключам... то есть с 3 - два массива, с 6 - два и с 2 - три

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я по вопросу понял, что нужна максимальная _подгруппа_. В любом случае, map собирается, из него можно выбрать что угодно

Comment: мммм... если максимальная подгруппа, то значит я не так понял ТС. Хотя вкрадывается сомнение, что скорее ты...)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну он пока молчит, поэтом еще неизвестно кто именно его не понял :-)

Comment: "а должно быть разбито по дублирующимся ключам... то есть с 3 - два массива"... Вы правы

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK, добавь в вопрос побольше примеров, что должно на выходе быть

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK, обновил ответ